# Is there anyway I can InitializeComponent another contentpage from a different page via a "click" for example?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there anyway you can "restart"/initialize a page from a click (from another page)? I am working with a rootpage cointaining a Master Detail Page and a contentpage, and I would want them to not Initialize their Components together as they are right now. 
Maybe an option is to (if it is possible) make a clickevent with the Master Detail Page Icon if the InitializeComponent question is not possible.

But of course it would be more handy if I could seperate the two pages somehow. I am trying to come up with something below that would initialize another pages components.

```
button.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
var ourStartPage = new StartPage ();
ourStartPage.InitializeComponent ();

}
```

Comment: just create a public method in the page and have it call InitializeComponent.  I don't think messing with the page lifecycle like this is a great idea, but there is nothing technically preventing you from doing it.

Comment: but how do i reach other pages Initializecomponents? When I do my code above I cannot reach (for example) startpages Initializecomponent when I am currently working in the Masterdetailpage page. I can only write it and initialize the current pages current components.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean with public method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Page1 : ContentPage {

  public Page1() {

    // comment out the default InitializeComponent()
    // InitializeComponent();
  }

  // create a public method to do the init instead
  public void InitThisPage() {

    InitializeComponent();
  }

}
```

Comment: Any idea why it works when I test it via the log System.Dianogstics.Debug.Writeline ("test"); but when I try to for example change the text of a label it doesnt?

Comment: You're trying to do that from the public method?  I'd guess that you're either not invoking it on the UI thread, or you're calling the wrong instance of your page.

Comment: I both tried to load the particular function I want loaded and also load the whole page (initializecomponent) but the weird thing is that it only works in the log when I test it. But when I try to make things visible/change texts and whatnot. Nothing happens. I can make a new thread about it later tonight if you think it is a bit offtopic. I follow your code. And it reaches the function when I test it via the log but when I try to make actual changes it doesnt run.